# Segmentation Fault While Reading File in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am still very new to the c language and I am playing with reading files for the first time.  I had similar code to this code which used to run perfectly fine but now I am running into issues.  I  keep getting the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` every time I try to run this program.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char ssn[9];
};

void make_arrays() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("students.db", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    long num_students = size / sizeof(struct student);
    printf("There are %ld students in the file", num_students);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv[]) {
    make_arrays();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the return values of `fopen`, `fseek`

Comment: Seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Especially how to use a debugger to catch crashes "in action" to see where in *your* code they happen, and then examine relevant variables and their values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude or, the simpler way, printf counter (possibly with some delay) before and after every line that could cause a crash and see the last value printed.

Comment: OP: `long num_students = size / sizeof(struct student);` what the hell?

Comment: @Edenia What about it? But the file should be opened in binary mode.

Comment: @Edenia In the shown code, the only reasonable possibility of a crash is `fopen` failing and then passing a null pointer to `fseek`. We can't tell for *certain* (which is why debugging is needed) but since there's no actual reading of the file that can't be a cause.

Comment: It has already been said. Many times: Check return values of all functions, especially `fopen`. Here every function can return error.

Comment: @Edenia How is that simpler when you can literally just look at the stack trace of a crash and see exactly what happened?

Comment: @melpomene Not everyone likes to use debugger and read stack traces. Use whatever suits you.

Comment: Are there platforms that don't support `stat()` but do support `SEEK_END` in binary mode (which C doesn't require)?

Comment: Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)`, has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not assuredly end in the initial shift state.

Comment: -quoted from C11 standard n1517

Comment: It also depends on the contents of the file, which are not presented here. I'd also check value of `size`

Comment: I changed the "r" to a "a" and it works fine now. Guess I'll just go with that.

Comment: That's a *bad* solution. Read e.g. [this `fopen` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen), especially about the difference between the `"r"` and `"a"` options, and what happens if the file doesn't exist. That should help you understand why using the *append* option make it seem to work.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll be sure to check that out. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Edenia printf debugging is fine if that's your preference, but be sure you always put an explicit fflush call after each line, or the program might crash while the last successful line of output is still in the buffer, thus making it seem as though it crashed earlier than it did.

Comment: @Istanford53: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 2):

The segmentation fault might be caused by `fopen` failing to open the file.

You should always test for such failures and exit with an informative message.

Also note that, if the file is indeed binary, it should be open in binary mode to avoid end of line translation:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("students.db", "rb");
```

Also change the prototype for `main` to `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or simply `int main()`. There are too many stars in `char **argv[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to mark my answer as accepted, just want to inspire people to write code so that it is readable and safe. Don't be lazy to write code like this where quality is a factor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/stat.h>

struct student /* Magic numbers everywhere */
{
    char first[30];
    char last[30];
    char ssn[9];

};




void* handle_nullptr_error (void* ptr, char *action, int code)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to %s\n", action);

        exit(code);
    }

    printf("Succeeded to %s\n", action);

    return ptr;
}

int handle_nonzero_error (int val, char *action, int code)
{
    if(val != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to %s\n", action);

        exit(code);
    }

    printf("Succeeded to %s\n", action);

    return val;
}

int handle_negval_error (int val, char *action, int code)
{
    if(val < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to %s\n", action);

        exit(code);
    }

    printf("Succeeded to %s\n", action);

    return val;
}




/** This function is not guaranteed to be portable and work (but it will at least fail properly),
 * because not all systems and/or library implementations support `SEEK_END` in files
 * opened in text mode, as specified by @mode
 * Moreover, in binary mode it will behave in an undefined manner, because different systems
 * may store files data completely differently. In most cases it will succeed, just don't
 * write code that crashes if not.
 */
long int get_file_charcount (const char *filename, char* mode)
{
    FILE*       fp      = NULL;
    long int    fpSize  = 0L;

    /* Alignment for complicated function calls (for e.g where functions are passed as arguments) */
    fp = handle_nullptr_error       (fopen(filename, mode),     "open file.",           1);

    (void)handle_nonzero_error      (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END),    "seek end position.",   2);

    fpSize = handle_negval_error    (ftell(fp),                 "tell position.",       3);

    fclose(fp); /* - May fail, as well */

    return fpSize;
}

/** This function depends on POSIX headers and it is unix-conformant, although there are still
 * some exceptions.
 *
 * Note that the value returned is the length of the contents of the symbolic link,
 * and does not count any trailing null pads. The value is ought to be system-specific.
 */
_off64_t get_file_size (const char *filename)
{
    struct stat st = {0};

    (void)handle_negval_error(stat(filename, &st), "get file size.", (-1));

    return st.st_size;
}

/** A validation function should first determine whether file's size is
 * actually dividable by `sizeof(struct STUDENT_DESCRIPTION);`.
 *
 * Further more you can use `get_file_size()` as an alternative to
 * `get_file_charcount()`. In the latter case, make sure you to specify the
 * appropriate mode, "r" for text files and "rb" for binary files.
 */
void make_arrays ()
{
    long int    size            = get_file_charcount("myfile.txt", "r");
    long int    num_students    = size / sizeof(struct STUDENT_DESCRIPTION);

    printf("size of file: %ld\n", size);

    printf("There are %ld students in the file", num_students);
}




int main (void)
{
    make_arrays();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```